# How to point github project at Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github, github-for-windows

I have cloned a github repository and would now like to import the project into Eclipse.

The project name is 'myproject' and when cloned it is then created in my github repository :

```
c:\\users\\myrepo
```

Here are the files that were cloned :

[image]

The repository exists in a location which is different to the Eclipse workspace. How can I use this project within an Eclipse workspace ?

I'm going to answer this question as I found an answer while writing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Eclipse create a new project and set its type to the project type, in below example Scala :

[image]

Click next and on new dialog enter path to project location on local git directory :

[image]

Verify project setup is correct and click 'Finish'. The project should then be added to Eclipse and any changes made will be reflected in the git repository and so will be recognized by 'github for windows'

Answer (score -1):

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_the_import_wizard and follow the path of Adding the clone you've already made.

Comment: thats tailored for EGit, im referring to github for windows : windows.github.com